# custom qHash method is not being called

Tags: c++, qt, hash, hashmap

I'm using QPoint as a key in a QHash, and following the documentation, I implemented a global qHash method for QPoint like so:

```cpp
inline uint qHash(QPoint const &key, uint seed) {
  size_t hash = qHash(QPair<int, int>(key.x(), key.y()), seed);
  qDebug() << hash;
  return hash;
}
```

I'm using it like this

```cpp
class HashTest {
  public:
    QHash<QPoint, QColor> hash;
    void addPixel(QPoint pt, QColor color) {
      hash[pt] = color;
    }
}
```

The insert still happens correctly, but it's not using my qHash function. Even if I comment out the qHash function, it still inserts. Considering that QPoint is documented as not having a qHash function, is this expected behavior?

**EDIT: Minimal Reproducible Example**

```cpp
#include <QDebug>
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QHash>
#include <QPoint>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
#if QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(6, 0, 0)
  QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif

  QHash<QPoint, int> hash;
  QPoint key = QPoint(0, 0);
  hash[key] = 3;
  qDebug() << hash[key]; // 3
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @kiner_shah I'm sorry, I really thought what I had earlier qualified. At any rate here's an example

Comment: The example you provided doesn't call `qHash` anywhere nor link it.

Comment: which is exactly the point. Why does this work seeing as `qHash` is not supposed to be implementeed in `QPoint`

Comment: If it is implemented, but not documented, then I don't expect my inlined version to work. The code below seems to indicate this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

qHash for QPoint might not be documented but [sure is defined](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/tools/qpoint.h?h=6.2.1#n236):

```
Q_CORE_EXPORT size_t qHash(QPoint key, size_t seed = 0) noexcept;
```

Comment: I think it was added in Qt 6, right? I use 5.12 and I don't have it in that file

Comment: [Looks like they added it after the Qt 6 feature freeze](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-86457)

Comment: got it. So having an inlined version still makes sense for users compiling on lower versions of QT. Thanks!